# Isolated storage specific IO vs non iso-storage IO

Tags: c#

We have been working on a program that writes data to the isolated storage. This program uses the normal System.IO namespace for writing, reading and saving files to the isolated storage. In some cases we get Access Denied errors.

While digging into the information about the isolated storage, we noticed that there are specific isolated storage methods for accessing and storing data. However we could not determine why we should use the System.IO namespace methods over the isolated storage specific ones.

Are the Access Denied errors we see a result from using the System.IO namespace?

Apart from the security benefits of using the Isolated Storage methods for writing etc, why should we use this over the normal System.IO namespace?

Comment: Perhaps read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage The isolated storage API is designed specifically for being used for isolated storage, so it has many features that you don't have in the standard File/Directory APIs

Comment: We know that is specifically designed to be used with the isolated storage. But were unable to find information regarding the access denied errors when using the System.IO namespace over the Isolated storage specific ones.

Comment: Access denied can be anything, you aren't providing enough information. Is it that the file is already in use, lack of permissions, or what exactly happens? Trying to figure out the error is kind of pointless though since you should be using the isolated storage APIs anyway